# Running shell script: How to include commands in the output as if typed interactively

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

How can I run/source a shell script (bash if that matters) and have the output *include* the commands within the script? I'd like to redirect the output to a file as in

```
$ ./my_script > output.txt
```

and have the `output.txt` file contain the commands from the script as if I had entered its contents into a terminal interactively and then copy-pasted the terminal window's contents into a file.

Bonus points for solutions that make the commands visually different from the output lines, as in a terminal with the preceding `$`.

Comment: @steeldriver The question is different: I don't want to enter those commands interactively, I want to run a script non-interactively but have the output look as if I had entered all script commands manually.

Comment: ah OK I see ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script add the following line before any commands (this writes each command to stderror before executing it):

`set -x`

then start your script:

`./my_script > output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: +1, I knew it would be something simple like this... strange I couldn't find it easily.